# Webpage with a button to download with Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, urllib3

I am learning Python and am attempting to automate a download of a file from a webpage. I have not tested it yet because I need to know if I am on the right track.  I expect to have the script perform what pressing the button on the webpage would do which is create a file and start a download of that file.

Below is the information from the page with the button:

> //input type="submit" name="export" value="Export"//
>
> //form name="export" action="/cgi-bin/configuration.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="export"//

```
import urllib3
import requests

req = requests.post('<IP Addy>/cgi-bin/configuration.cgi', 'Export')
with open('file.data', 'wb') as file:
file.write(req.content)
```

Comment: It seems that the HTML only provides uploading and there's no way to download the file.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something or not explaining correctly.  The button has the word "export" as it's name.  When I click on the button, the web browser will then prompt for a download of the file.